# At Django pagination template code <a href="?page=...">, why does url link start with "?page="?

Tags: python, html, django, url, django-templates

At Django pagination template code

```
<a href="?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}>
```

why does url link start with `?page=`?

Why is there no root(?) url in this code?

for example, at url pattern `path('post/', views.PostLV.as_view(), name='post_list')`,

```
<a href="post/?page={{page_obj.previous_page_number}}>
```

I think `post/?page=...` is right than `?page=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there no root(?) url in this code?

Because the page is normally the *same* one. By defining an URL with `?page=2`, you will make a request to the *same* path, except that the querystring will be replaced with `?=page`.

So if the current page is `/post`, then it will visit `/post?page=2`, this is documented in the [URL specifications [whatwg.org]](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#relative-url-with-fragment-string):

> A relative-URL-with-fragment string must be a [relative-URL string](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#relative-url-string), optionally followed by U+0023 (`#`) and a URL-fragment string.

Or the [*Resolve a string as a relative URL* section on the URL specifications [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-url-20120524/#resolve-a-string-as-a-relative-url):

> 4. If the first character of relative-url is a `"?"` character, the resolved URL is relative-url [resolved as a query-relative URL](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-url-20120524/#resolve-a-string-as-a-query-relative-url-0); abort these steps.

with as steps:

> 1. Given a string relative-url and a parsed URL base-url, let resolved-url be:
>
>    - base-url’s scheme
>    - concatenated with `"://"`,
>    - concatenated with base-url’s authority,
>    - concatenated with base-url’s path,
>    - concatenated with relative-url.
>
> The resolved URL is resolved-url parsed as an absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. Have a nice day.